# Browser Plugin Detection

Tags: javascript, browser, plugins

Anyone know how to determine if a particular plugin is installed on a user's browser?  The plugin in question is AlternaTIFF.

Comment: So it looks like i need to determine the user's browser then run either jeffamaphone or olliej's code to determine if the plugin is installed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe `navigator.plugins` gives you access to that information, it has name, description, and supported mimetypes of each plugin.

Answer (score 0):

AlternaTIFF has some code that does that, it looks like: http://www.alternatiff.com/testpage.html

Answer (score 0):

For IE just try to [create it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7sw4ddf8(VS.85).aspx).

```
var installed = true;
try {
  newObj = new ActiveXObject(YOUROBJECT.whatever);
} catch {
  installed = false;
}
```